# Compare 2 Text Cells/Ignore Null Cells/More Text

Tags: excel, null, compare, excel-2013

I have files that we need to track during reviews, we have 2 cells:  Reviewers and Attendees

I need to know if the text matches OR if Attendees contains more text than Reviewers AND ignore null.

This is what I get now:

```
Reviewers              Attendees              Participation
Smith, Bubba, Toby     Smith, Bubba, Toby           True
                                                    True
Smith, Bubba, Toby     Smith, Bubba, Toby, Fred     False
Smith, Bubba, Toby     Smith, Bubba                 False
```

I need to get:

```
Reviewers              Attendees              Participation
Smith, Bubba, Toby     Smith, Bubba, Toby           Equal
                                                    Null
Smith, Bubba, Toby     Smith, Bubba, Toby, Fred     More
Smith, Bubba, Toby     Smith, Bubba                 Less
```

Not sure if this is possible, or if I need to look at it from a different perspective.
The owners of this spreadsheet are not going to agree to change the format of the Reviewers or Attendees columns.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!~

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
=IF(AND(A2="",B2=""),"Null",IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))=LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","")),"Equal",IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))>LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","")),"Less","More")))
```